# Bootstrap Responsive - Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsive

I've created a very simple landing page using Bootstrap.
As I was designing it I was working on the responsive breakpoints and in Chrome, they all looked and worked great.

Now that I've uploaded my site, I realized that the responsive isn't working. In desktop I have no issues, but in mobile the text and button sizes remain the same.

www.woodtechms.com

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you uploaded this files to the server? `css/bootstrap.css`, `css/bootstrap.min.css` and `css/custom-landing.css`. In case not, you can use the Bootstrap's CDN. Look at this http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn, for more information.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've uploaded all three files to the server.  Any other toughts?

Comment: Put the code in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's due to missing meta tags inside `header`.

[Here's Bootstrap template](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

I've also added `img-responsive` class to your logo image and then the logo scales down as it supposed to.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but I also found the other error I had.

Comment: I added these lines to my CSS:

<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

Answer (score 0):

It does work but only for screen sizes more than 768 and less than 900px as written in your custom-css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 900px) {

    /* ---- Logo Woodtech ---- */
    .logo {
        margin-top: 230px;
    }

    /* ---- Title ---- */
    h2 {
        font-size: 5.9rem;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        line-height: 70px;
    }

    /* ---- Text ---- */
    p {
        font-size: 34px;
        padding-bottom: 34px;
    }

    /* ---- Button ---- */
    .contact-button {
        width: 400px;
        font-size: 4rem;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

If you want it to change styles for other widths then you need to add more media queries like the one added in your css.

For e.g., if you want the button width to be 300px in between screen size 600px and 800px you can write the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px){
   .contact-button{
   width:300px;
}
}
```

And likewise you can add styles for other elements at different widths.

Comment: Thank you!  I am having a very strange problem (another one) with the background image. I had it set in the <body> tag. Then I read that it should be in the <html> tag. When I set the image to the <html> tag, the image would show only after the body content finished.  (all this in mobile). When checking in chrome or firefox, it works, but when I check it in my mobile (Moto) it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: It might be bacause of the image size that it takes time to load. Also it sepends on the internet speed as well. You can try compressing your images as much as possible. Also make sure that when your site goes in production you minimize other assets like html,css, js as well. This will improve your site performance and will give you a better user experience.